# Appropriate Date Format in R

Tags: r, date, format

Below is the current data frame I'm working with. I'm trying to get the date in a workable format so I can plot data etc. How can I get this into an appropriate format that R likes?

```
head(HD1)
   index                                    date temperature humidity dewpoint
2      0 Sun Apr 19 2020 16:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)        13.4     43.4      1.3
4      1 Sun Apr 19 2020 17:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)        -1.2     70.6     -5.9
6      2 Sun Apr 19 2020 18:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)        -2.0     76.0     -5.7
8      3 Sun Apr 19 2020 19:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)        -1.6     72.9     -5.8
10     4 Sun Apr 19 2020 20:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)        -2.2     75.3     -6.0
12     5 Sun Apr 19 2020 21:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)        -3.1     81.9     -5.8
```

This is the "`date`" format: `Sun Apr 19 2020 16:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)`

I've tried to `mutate` the date, `stringr` to delete characters, and `as.date` (which obviously didn't work), and `anytime` package.

Comment: Can you let us know what you will be plotting? Weather parameters as a function of time? Scatter plots of the weather parameters? Aggregates, e.g. averages, per day? 
If the first, you would like to reshape the DF into a long shape. Have a look at `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the date column? If you're trying to convert it to a proper datetime class, try the `lubridate` package from the tidyverse, which might be easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes your formats are so "out there" that it helps to read the dreaded manual and supply a format string:

```
R> vals <- c("Sun Apr 19 2020 16:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)", 
             "Sun Apr 19 2020 17:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)", 
             "Sun Apr 19 2020 17:01:06 GMT-0600 (MDT)")
R> as.POSIXct(vals, , "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2020-04-19 16:01:06 CDT" "2020-04-19 17:01:06 CDT" 
[3] "2020-04-19 17:01:06 CDT"
R>
```

The keys are `%a` for the short weekday, `%b` for the months -- and the rest is the pretty standard for `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, albeit shuffled.